# dropbox won't start apparently due to permission problem

Tags: dropbox

I'm trying to install the dropbox package for linux available on [this site][1]. After installing it with:

```
dpkg -i dropbox_2015.10.28_amd64.deb
```

I got some dependency problem:

```
Unpacking dropbox (2015.10.28) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dropbox:
  dropbox depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.20.1); however:
   Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package dropbox (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dropbox
```

So I installed the required packages and the dropbox installation is fully successful:

```
Dropbox installation successfully completed! You can start Dropbox from your applications menu.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...

Current status: 0 (-1) broken.
```

So I tried to start the dropbox service with `dropbox start -i` so that it downloads and install the most version of dropbox but then I got this message:

```
This is usually because of a permissions error. Storing your home folder on a network share can also cause an error.

Get more help at https://www.dropbox.com/c/help/permissions_error

Please contact Dropbox support with the following info for help:

/tmp/dropbox_errorwAmEC4.txt
```

I'm sure that I have the correct permission and that I don't have any space problem. But nothing works...

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I found the solution by looking at the last line of the file `/tmp/dropbox_errorwAmEC4.txt`:

```
ImportError: libxslt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It turns out that the package `libxslt1.1` (on debian) was not installed but required. By installing it, the problem was solved.